# how to return specific output related to conditions being met in, using R data table

Tags: r, if-statement, datatable

i am trying to use data table package. i want to find out a way to create a new column based on specific conditions in 3 variable which is related to a calculation.

```
#this is my dataset  
dput(dt[1:5])
structure(list(cashtype = c("", "", "", "", ""), quantity = c(1200000, 
1400000, 2400000, 2500000, 810000), price_mid = c(100.0385, 102.5583, 
92.7059, 108.515, 113.8505), value_mid = c(1200462.3, 1189302.74, 
2224941.6, 2712875, 922189.41), currency_price = c("GBP", "EUR", 
"GBP", "GBP", "GBP"), currency_value = c("GBP", "GBP", "GBP", 
"GBP", "GBP")), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x15f28c0>)`
```

I need to check the calculations for this large dataset. not all the numbers add up. but i have a way to check so. which is the 'value_mid' column divided by 'quantity' multiplied by 100. this should add up to the price_mid column. using the column valid to check. after this i would like to ideally turn the 'valid' observations into "True" that match 'price_mid' & those that do not into "False".

`dt[,valid:= (value_mid/quantity)*100]`

I'm not to sure how to use a ifelse function within datatable. was finding it confusing. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
dt[,valid := price_mid == (value_mid/quantity)*100][]
   cashtype quantity price_mid value_mid currency_price currency_value valid
1:           1200000  100.0385 1200462.3            GBP            GBP FALSE
2:           1400000  102.5583 1189302.7            EUR            GBP FALSE
3:           2400000   92.7059 2224941.6            GBP            GBP FALSE
4:           2500000  108.5150 2712875.0            GBP            GBP  TRUE
5:            810000  113.8505  922189.4            GBP            GBP FALSE
```

To get around rounding problems you could try something with `round`:

```
dt[,valid := round(price_mid,4) == round((value_mid/quantity)*100,4)][]
   cashtype quantity price_mid value_mid currency_price currency_value valid
1:           1200000  100.0385 1200462.3            GBP            GBP  TRUE
2:           1400000  102.5583 1189302.7            EUR            GBP FALSE
3:           2400000   92.7059 2224941.6            GBP            GBP  TRUE
4:           2500000  108.5150 2712875.0            GBP            GBP  TRUE
5:            810000  113.8505  922189.4            GBP            GBP  TRUE
```

Comment: thank you for your response. it works fine. my issue is with R rounding significant digits off the number. if you perform the operation (value/quantity then *100) in the calculator you should get 100.038525. but R rounds. how would i fix this issue? as it comes out false in some cases when it should be true. thanks.

Comment: works perfect @IanCampbell. you're the man. Thank you

Comment: Hi,  very much same problem as before. some values in the calculator are getting rounded as still getting a false. any more potential suggestions many thanks